# Updated Gorelik principle

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

One version of the Gorelik principle is the following: Let $E,X$ be Banach spaces and suppose $U:E\to X$ is a Lipschitz isomorphism (that is, a Lipschitz bijection whose inverse is also Lipschitz). Then there exists $\theta_1=\theta_1(U)>0$ such that for any subspace $E_1$ of $E$ such that $\dim E/E_1<\infty$ and any $r>0$, there exists a norm compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $$\theta_1 rB_X\subset K+U(rB_{E_1}).$$

I would like to know about the following improvement: Does there exist a constant $\theta_2=\theta_2(U)>0$ such that for any $r>0$ and any $E_1$ with $\dim E/E_1<\infty$, there exists a norm compact subset $K_1$ of $X$ such that for any $E_2$ with $\dim E/E_2<\infty$, there exists a norm compact subset $K_2$ of $X$ such that $$\theta_2 B_X \subset K_1+K_2+U\Bigl(\frac{r}{2}B_{E_1}+\frac{r}{2}B_{E_2}\Bigr)?$$  If so, how does $\theta_2$ compare to $\theta_1$?

There is an obvious extension: For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, does there exist $\theta_n=\theta_n(U)>0$ such that for any $r>0$, for any $E_1$ with $\dim E/E_1<\infty$, there exists a norm compact subset $K_1$ of $X$ such that for any $E_2$ with $\dim E/E_2<\infty$, there exists a norm compact subset $K_2$ of $X$ such that $\ldots$ for any $E_n$ with $\dim E/E_n<\infty$, there exists a norm compact subset $K_n$ of $X$ such that $$\theta_n B_X\subset K_1+K_2+\ldots+K_n+U\Bigl(\frac{r}{n}B_{E_1}+\frac{r}{n}B_{E_2}+\ldots + \frac{r}{n}B_{E_n}\Bigr)?$$ If so, can these numbers be chosen to satisfy $\inf_n \theta_n>0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This site doesn't really work well as a "Prove a conjecture" site, though there's exceptions of course. Not to say it's wrong or anything, progress can only be achieved with new ideas after all! Rather, with the sheer amount of questions it's sometimes difficult for us volunteers to decide what's worth working/thinking on, and so you might profit from giving arguments as to why you think your conjecture would hold or would not hold. Especially as questions get more advanced and the pool of people being able to answer thus becomes smaller.